# I cannot input the whole number

Tags: javascript, input, textbox, mask

I am trying to mask a textbox so a user can type two kinds of documents. Here is the code in which I'm trying to mask, accordingly to the length of the document:

```js
$("#TextBoxDoc").keypress(function () {
             try {
                 $("#TextBoxDoc").unmask();
             } catch (e) { }

             var len = $("#TextBoxDoc").val().length;

             if (len < 11) {
                 $("#TextBoxDoc").mask("999.999.999-99");
             } else if (len >= 11) {
                 $("#TextBoxDoc").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
             }
         });
```

The textbox code is this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDoc" CssClass="form-control" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

The only problem, is that when I try to write the input, it only allows me to write one character. When I press another number, it substitutes the first one.

I know it has something to do with the keypress event, but I have no idea how to overcome this.

Comment: I created identical textbox to yours and binded the same function, and it seems to work fine for me on Chrome. I suspect it could be a browser issue. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: I tried in the 3 main browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox) and it keeps giving me the same problem. I tried changing the textbox, or even rewriting the function, but it does not work.

Comment: What about creating a minimal example that demonstrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on jsfiddle. It works perfectly with simple html and jquery. I think there is something to do with asp.net. I'm not sure what it is, but hope it helped.

https://jsfiddle.net/8hsgzpma/`example`